# Devide the time series data into groups using SQL

Tags: sql, database, grouping

Now we have the battery usage data, mainly the voltage data.
The voltage decline as the day goes by. After a few days, the battery would be changed and the voltage would go back to the maximum value.

In this dataset, I hope to flag the 3 cycles the battery be used from the maximum voltage to the minimum voltage by some SQL clause if possible

| voltage | date |
| --- | --- |
| 4.2 | 2022-1-1 |
| 4.1 | 2022-1-10 |
| 4.0 | 2022-1-20 |
| 3.8 | 2022-1-23 |
| 3.6 | 2022-2-3 |
| 4.1 | 2022-2-5 |
| 4.0 | 2022-2-7 |
| 3.9 | 2022-2-25 |
| 3.8 | 2022-3-12 |
| 4.2 | 2022-3-15 |
| 4.1 | 2022-3-20 |
| 4.0 | 2022-3-23 |
| 3.5 | 2022-3-30 |

After the operation, the dataset should be like this:

| voltage | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4.2 | 2022-1-1 | 1 |
| 4.1 | 2022-1-10 | 1 |
| 4.0 | 2022-1-20 | 1 |
| 3.8 | 2022-1-23 | 1 |
| 3.6 | 2022-2-3 | 1 |
| 4.1 | 2022-2-5 | 2 |
| 4.0 | 2022-2-7 | 2 |
| 3.9 | 2022-2-25 | 2 |
| 3.8 | 2022-3-12 | 2 |
| 4.2 | 2022-3-15 | 3 |
| 4.1 | 2022-3-20 | 3 |
| 4.0 | 2022-3-23 | 3 |
| 3.5 | 2022-3-30 | 3 |

Comment: Just use `lag()` and then count up the times the difference moves the opposite direction (up). Standard gaps and islands technique.

Comment: I have tried to use lag() to flag the point the battery is changed,  but it is still difficult to divide the battery cycle to 3 groups

Comment: `with data as (select *, lag(voltage) over (order by "date") as last_voltage from T) select *, count(case when voltage > last_voltage then 1 end) over (order by "date") as "type" from data`